# runtime error 438 object doesn't support this property or method internet explorer

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use a loop to get the data from web to excel sheet. I will attach the sheet and also paste the code here. Please help me with this. Thank you.

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Row = Range("Number").Row And _
Target.Column = Range("Number").Column Then
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://www.truecaller.com/search/in/" & Range("Number").Value
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Set Doc = IE.document
Dim sdd As String
sdd = Doc.getElementsByClassName("profile-name").innerText
MsgBox sdd

End If

End Sub
```

---

WHEN I USE ABOVE CODE I GET THE BELOW ERROR

---

> Run-time error '438':
>   Object doesn't support this property or method

.

---

Comment: Why is it that no one ever seems to think that including the line number that generated the error is important?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3bc9Owb0D9zXzFOc0dnLWxJWHc

Comment: sdd = Doc.getElementsByClassName("profile-name").innerText-----------------is the line which created error

Comment: You see how .get**Elements**ByClassName is plural? .getElementsByClassName returns a collection, not a single object.

Comment: I tried element instead of elements didn't work

Comment: Try Doc.getElementsByClassName("profile-name")(0).innerText then learn how to deal with a collection.

Comment: Bravo.......... You are a gem

Answer (score 0):

See how .get**Elements**ByClassName is plural? [.getElementsByClassName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975198(v=vs.85).aspx) returns a collection, not a single object. In essence, you are trying to treat an array of integers as a single integer; they are **not** the same thing.

You cannot simply remove the *s*; there is no getElementByClassName function. However, you can ask for the first element the same way you specify an individual integer within an array of integers.

```
sdd = Doc.getElementsByClassName("profile-name")(0).innerText
```